# Are there any gotchas to using safety capacitors (X1/X2 box style) in the construction of a filter?

Tags: capacitor

I guess this is just not done for whatever reason.  I hit Google and even after over 20 mins could not really find any information on point.

I've got a fair amount of .47uF and .68uF X1/X2 metallized polyester film (I've got data sheets on a couple of them, these are all box) safety capacitors.

I want to use them to make a DAC reconstruction filter.  I have not yet decided on the topology, though.  I'm thinking a 3 to 5 pole LC combined with a 3 pole Sallen Key active. I mean the capacitors would be perfect, high ratings, good D, not ceramic (the ceramic NP0 would be too small.)

If they were not rated, I would not think twice, but I'm just wanting to make sure they won't cause problems based on their construction.  Was there something done to enable them to be rated that would cause problems? The datasheets does not say, nor could I find/see any complaints.

Datasheet: [Okaya PA Series](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/mm5/graphics/H09/PA224.pdf)

Comment: What does the datasheet say about inductivity? Is it in the acceptable range for your filter?

Comment: Don't see it.  I've linked the datasheet.  The caps I have are that series. Not the newer PA-LE on their website.  Max freq for the DAC will be around 100Khz and I was going to amplify after the filter(why amplify junk?)

Comment: "safety capacitors" are either X-rated or Y-rated capacitors. There's a tag for `x-capacitors`, you could use that.

Comment: Then I think a synonym might be a good idea.  I did not think to search for x-.

Comment: You might find that you can't get close tolerance devices in X rated capacitors (like asking for +/- 0.01mm tolerances on a hammer), but other than that they are the ideal low/mid frequency filter cap

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you.  They will either be taking part in a simple LPF for a Sigma-Delta ADC, part of a reconstruction filter for a x10 over-sampled DAC or analog digital power line filter..  Is far as I know, none of those applications are really precision applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was there something done to enable them to be rated that would cause problems?

No.

> Are there any gotchas?

Other than possibly enough inductance to affect performance, no.

Safety rated capacitors are more robust than equivalent film or ceramic unrated parts.  They also are almost always larger and more expensive, especially in a low-voltage application.  But other than an ESL (Equivalent Series Inductance) that is much higher than that of a 25 V or 50 V part, I don't think there are other issues.

Comment: These are all pulls of one type or another, so cost does not apply here.  As far as ESL goes, I'm going to be hooking them up to a 2 or 3 9mH inductors so it will just  help... :)  I'll have to see, but unless I hear a show stopper in the next couple of hours, I'll accept your answer and build the circuit.  And if these things kill it, I've got some PE cap[s(I would rather save these for audio usage though.)

Answer (score 2):

Plastic film caps of all kinds are the closest to an ideal cap in this size( except motor start-run caps ( which are designed for slightly higher ESR).

There are subtle differences but PP X-Y caps are about the best (exc. TEFLON $) for the  parameters you  mention and also the good choice for small value S&H , FOR touch screen reference caps and low  leakage for Integrators.

Inductance will add only about 0.5nH/mm for short L/D ratios.  Internal foil can be found by SRF frequency  tests but I suspect they’ll will outperform MOST 150 MHz GBW Op Amps operating at filters well below 10MHz.

The reason I mentioned that is that, you tried to make an active notch LPF with high Q at the DAC spectral peak like Q=100 at 100kHz for Class D,E filters you need >150MHz of BW.  But passive filters no problem. Just look for the **Ripple current rating.**  which comes into play at high power levels. THe Dissipation Factor is a percentage of the power transferred and filtered out by the filter (losses). Since L presents a high impedance, your can export your Falstad Model into the main time domain site ( export text...import text and then add ESR and scope average power on that ESR computed automatically= by selecting the scope properties for Power , Avg, min,max on that added non-ideal cap and inductor.

I highly recommend you model it in http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-filt-lopass-l.html and choose from >circuits> high order passive filters and choose the one you want and the order and then add DCR,ESR if you want realism for you source RdsOn and speaker load R1+R2//L = 8 Ohms for example as that may affect the filter.

They  are also the best caps for crossover filters in speakers and reactive offline 5W non-isolated step-down transformers.

Comment: I guess it would not have hurt to add the DAC application which is not audio.  This is part of the excitation circuit for my LCR meter, I'm working on in my coupious spare time.

Comment: Ah . OK the only gotcha on PP caps I found after testing 5k of them with my LCR meter is you have to screen for 1% tolerance when you buy 10%.  I put them in film containers for each 1% increment.  I hope you are using a CC sine wave to measure impedance and phase shift. For that I might not use a DAC but rather a true sine wave Oscillator into a voltage controlled Howland converter CC. At 120Hz, 1k, 10k and 100kHz. .. maybe not 1 MHz unless you have 100MHz GBW Op Amps. Rail to rail.

Comment: I'm running DAC -> filter -> modified howland CC.  I just need from about 120Khz and down.  I've got a 1.8Mhz+ VNA with I-V head I built a couple of years ago for RF.  I'm using these STM32F3 DACs at 1Msps, even without filtering they look decent on my Kikusui 5060.  I'd be willing to put them on the air after a simple RC low pass.  I may just do a 5 pole LC(which is what my VNA had originally) and call it a day.  I want them 0 and 180 to give me more ability.  And I may be running at less than 60Khz if the SDADCs barf at the 120Khz.

Comment: That’ll work. We used phase frequency PLL’s for Eddy  current R&D for a product in the 70’s It had 50 ppm resolution and calibrated within 0.1 degree and 0.01% for amplitude with a test coupon. It was all analog. With quadrature servos using Bourns Sin-Cos pots driven by Swiss gear motors for servo calibration on every test. It  could detect a molecular strain in Monel Steel tubing well before  a leak of heavy water or a pin hole created by 10k atmospheres of pressure as a 0 and 90 degree phase shift. With a moving inductive coil inside the miles of tubing guided by our automated Robot

Comment: Yeah, I had seen a nice circuit where the Howland was put into the feedback loop of the controling OpAmp.  Add in a digipot and it works. The DAC controls the freq and the Howland controls the levels(I need to add a DC bias circuit in there too).  The hardest part I'm having is which way to go;Auto-balancing bridge or some form of I-V.  It's a toss up.

Comment: I synthesized one a while ago that worked up to 1MHz , maybe I still have it around. All DC controlled. Freq. and current. But with analog switched caps

Comment: Well my VNA(built from a mish-mash of two+ QEX projects) goes +10Dbm to -70Dbm at 1.8Mhz to over 2.4Ghz.  I swapped out the original ADI PLL for a TI one and add a TI quad mixer.  Now I want a Spectrum Analyzer.  Maybe after I get this thing the way I like it. LOL

Comment: I used NE602 mixer, at 10MHz, to extract the quadrature component of conducted current. That current, converted back into voltage and mixed with the 90-degree-phase-shifted LO, was proportional to inductance. Result was zero-to-1,000nanoHenry inductance meter, with about 10nH resolution. Used the NE602 oscillator at 10MHz, and an external quadrature phase-shifter and discrete current source; since the inductors pass both DC and AC, the current source just dumps its steady-state plus quadrature 10MHz into the inductor-under-test. Concept was from RFDesign Magazine, about 1995, at 100KHz.

Comment: Sounds sweet, but most likely overkill for my purposes(Plus a lot of work, I'm lazy...:))   I built my VNA because I wanted to be able to be able build and test 900Mhz+ equipment, mostly filters to be truthful.